# I am having trouble updating MBProgressHUD in dispatch main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, upload, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to update MBProgressHUD in my controller.
From only showing a static message, i want to put either progressbar/progress percentage to show uploading process to user.

```
YBWeakSelf;
[[YBStorageManage shareManage]getCOSInfo:^(int code) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (code == 0) {
            [weakSelf startUpload];
        }
    });
}];
[self networkState];

-(void)startUpload{
YBWeakSelf;
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0);
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

NSString *filePath =_videoPath;
//传图片

dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_videoCoverImage);

    if (!imageData) {
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUD];
        [MBProgressHUD showError:YZMsg(@"请重新选择")];
        return;
    }
    UIImage *herfImg = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    NSString *imageName = [PublicObj getNameBaseCurrentTime:@".png"];
    [[YBStorageManage shareManage]yb_storageImg:herfImg andName:imageName progress:^(CGFloat percent) {
        
    }complete:^(int code, NSString *key) {
        //图片成功
        [weakSelf uploadimagesuccess:key];

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
});

dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    //传视频
    NSString *videoName = [PublicObj getNameBaseCurrentTime:@".mp4"];

    [[YBStorageManage shareManage]yb_storageVideoOrVoice:filePath andName:videoName progress:^(CGFloat percent) {
        
    } complete:^(int code, NSString *key) {
        //请求app业务服务器给标题
        [weakSelf uploadvideosuccess:key andTitle:mytitle];
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
});


//上传水印视频

NSString *mkfilePath =_videoWmkPath;

dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_videoWmkCoverImage);

    if (!imageData) {
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUD];
        [MBProgressHUD showError:YZMsg(@"请重新选择")];
        return;
    }
    UIImage *herfImg = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    NSString *imageName = [PublicObj getNameBaseCurrentTime:@"_mk .png"];
    [[YBStorageManage shareManage]yb_storageImg:herfImg andName:imageName progress:^(CGFloat percent) {
        
    }complete:^(int code, NSString *key) {
        //图片成功
        [weakSelf uploadWmkimagesuccess:key];

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
});

dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    //传视频
    NSString *videoName = [PublicObj getNameBaseCurrentTime:@"_mk.mp4"];

    [[YBStorageManage shareManage]yb_storageVideoOrVoice:mkfilePath andName:videoName progress:^(CGFloat percent) {
        
    } complete:^(int code, NSString *key) {
        //请求app业务服务器给标题
        [weakSelf uploadvideoWmksuccess:key andTitle:mytitle];
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
});
dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self requstAPPServceTitle:mytitle andVideo:_videokey andImage:_imagekey];
    });
    NSLog(@"任务完成执行");
}); }
```

How can i update MBProgressHUD to have a progress bar there ?
meanwhile there are 4 async in queue thread.
I want to take the `progress:^(CGFloat percent)` and put it in MBProgressHUD
Since it is an update view progress, i have to put it in main thread, right ?
I've tried several times, but always stuck at the end.

i've tried to put dispatch main in every `progress:^(CGFloat percent)`
but it always give a purple warning said `Thread running at QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED waiting on a thread without a QoS class specified. Investigate ways to avoid priority inversions`

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We generally cannot help if we can’t reproduce the problem (and we shouldn’t have to go through a lot of kruft to get there). And, to HangarRash’s observation, that link says “[DO NOT use images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question, then [format it as code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).”

Comment: The questions in my mind would be (a) what these “yb” routines do (i.e., we need to know whether these blocks are already called on the main queue or not); and (b) you say you’re getting that priority inversion error when you add code, but don’t show us the code that generated that error.

Comment: As an aside, semaphores should be removed.  (They are so susceptible to problems that they’re best considered an anti-pattern nowadays.) This can easily be refactored to eliminate the semaphores and `dispatch_group_async` and just `dispatch_group_enter` before your async calls and `dispatch_group_leave` in the final completion handler. That’s much simpler than what you have here and less brittle.

Comment: Also, be aware that the `wait` on one block can satisfied by the `signal` of a completely different async call. Not a big deal, but it’s something to be cautious about when using semaphores (but becomes moot when you retire them). Finally, note that your first `dispatch_semaphore_wait` is using a QoS for the duration, which is obviously a typo.

Comment: thanks for all the response guys, i am new here, i already edited the question.
Cheers

Comment: i think im gonna try it using dispatch_group_async and just dispatch_group_enter before my async calls and dispatch_group_leave in final completion handler, ill let you know the result @Rob

Comment: I would encourage you to retire `dispatch_group_async`, too. It is superfluous. Just enter/leave/notify.